# Redux - Unmount-Mount Component causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My app has the following state structure (simplified):

**State**

```
products: [ 
  {
    id: number
    name: string
    reviewIds: number[] // the ids of the reviews for a product
  }
],
reviews: [
  {
    id: number,
    content: string
  }
]
```

**Components**

`ProductDetail` and `Review`. A `ProductDetail` has a `ul` of `Review` components inside etc.

```
...
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      actions: bindActionCreators(ProductActions as any, dispatch)
    };
  }

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

export class ProductDetailComponent extends React.Component<ProductDetail.Props, ProductDetail.State> {

    constructor(props: ProductDetail.Props ) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //This actions is from REDUX
        this.props.actions.getReviews(this.props.product);
    }

    render() {
      return(
          <ul>
          {
              this.props.reviews.map((review) => {
                  return(<li> review.content </li>);
              })
          }
          </ul>
        )
    }
  }
```

This component gets unmount and mounted, which causes the problem

**Actions**

In the `componentDidMount` method of the `ProductDetail` I call an Action to `FETCH_API_REVIEW` to retrieve the reviews of the product that component is displaying.

That network call when success, it dispatches another action `REVIEW_API_SUCCESS`.
I have then 2 reducers that listen to that action.

**Reducers**

`Product Reducer` will put the ReviewsIds for the product in the `reviewsIds`.
`Review Reducer` will put the Review complete structure in the review array.

Product Reducer:

```
[Actions.REVIEW_API_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
        const reviews = action.payload.data;
        const productId = action.payload.productId;

        const reviewsIDs = reviews.map((review) => {
            return review.id;
        });

        const products = state.products.map((product) => {
            if(product.id === productId) {
                const newProduct = Object.assign({}, product, {reviewsIDs});
                return newProduct;
            }
            return product;
        })
        const newState = Object.assign({}, state, { products });

        return newState;
}
```

Review Reducer

```
[Actions.REVIEW_API_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
        const result = Object.assign({ }, state, {reviews: action.payload});
        return result;
    },
}
```

This, I believe is following the best practices detailed here http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html second approach.

The issue I am having is that whenever that happens I get my two components (Product and Reviews) unmounted and mounted back and then the API gets called again etc etc. Causing an infinite loop.

Can you point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong?
Tks!

Comment: Would help to see a your code for the Product and Review components.

Comment: i think some more relevant code example is in order here

Comment: In the meantime: dispatches an action > modify state > state change causes re-render > When component re-renders, dispatches an action > modify state ...

Comment: @Pineda I added some code examples.

Comment: @Pineda just to answer your question: When you mention re-render, does that mean, mount un mount, I thought the component should get new props pushed but not unmount/mount...

Comment: I meant re-render, if you're sure they are being unmounted, then maybe the state being modified is causing the a component higher up in your component tree to re-render which may be causing your loop.

Comment: ^^ Most likely this.

Comment: Can you add a code example where Product is being rendered?